# howto see ckeditor samples

Tags: browser, ckeditor, sample

Hello stackoverflow team

I've installed the ckeditor package as per the Quick Start Guide at https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_installation.html

Server is Apache running on CentOS 7

I'm stuck on the "Trying it out".
When I point my browser (Firefox 52.x) to the page
http://localhost/ckeditor/samples/index.html
The page displays *without* the ckeditor editing box.

What have I done wrong ?
I can use Firebug and can see the javascript has been loaded into the webpage, BUT its not displaying anything.

Also checked the Firefox for any add-on blockers, none detected.

And the same Firefox is using ckeditor to post this question !!

TIA's for any ideas and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Download Full package, install.

Now working as expected.  Previous attempt must have been an incomplete load.